# Logging user presence unidentified discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot called Timer Bot and I want it to log in when it goes offline and when it goes back online. I have enabled Presence Intent and added it to my client

```
Intents = Discord.Intents
const client = new Discord.Client({ws:{intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES]}});
```

When I run this script -

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let member = newPresence.member;
    if (member.id === '603517534720753686') {
        if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
            let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('788547135234375712');
            let text = "";
            if (newPresence.status === "online") {
                text = "**Hello @everyone, Timer Bot is now online! Thank you for your patience.**";
            } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
                text = "**@everyone Due to issues, Timer Bot is currently offline. We apologize for the inconvenience.**";
            }
            channel.send(text);
        }
    }
});
```

My console reads -

```
Logged in as Timer Bot Utilities#6525!
/home/runner/TimerUtilities/index.js:25
        if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/index.js:25:25)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:379:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

It looks like oldPresence is unidentified. Does anyone know why?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [oldPresence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) may be null, this is why status returns undefined

```
if (oldPresence && oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
...code
}
```